# Maven sites - how do I find them?

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

For every build on our build server, we create and deploy a Maven site. At the moment, we use Nexus 2.14 and its Maven Site repository.

Unfortunately, the only way to find a site for an artifact is clicking through the repositories view, opening the folders and then navigating to the `index.html`.

What could I do to "connect" Maven sites to their respective artifacts and make them easier to find (through search functions etc.)?

Comment: Can you clarify more on your requirements?

Comment: If a developer wants to look up the site for given artifact, this should be nice and easy - in the best case, it should be possible to link from the artifact (in Nexus) .

Comment: I do not have any automated way to achieve your requirement. But, I did face this issue in past. Just updated my answer with something that might be helpful.